# Provider model and performance

Tags: c#, .net, provider-model

Are there any performance implications with using the provider pattern?

Does it rely on reflection for each instantiation or anything?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the provider model usually involves a small amount of reflection, and therefore, there is going to be a little bit of a performance hit, however, it is only in the instantiation of the provider object. Once the object is instantiated, it is accessed as normal (usually via an interface). The performance versus a hard-coded model should have very little difference, but the gain you get from the programming perspective *far* outweighs any performance penalty. Assuming the provider actually may change one day. If not, just hard-code it.

Answer (score 1):

Providers are instanced once per app-domain. Although newing up an object via reflection is slower than doing it inline, it is still very, very fast. I would say there is no performance concern for most business apps.